# Is there a way of expanding sin(a*b)?

Tags: trigonometry

There are identities for the sine of sum but are there for sine of product ? Had someone come up with this ? Or is it even possible to rewrite the $sin(a*b)$?

Comment: I haven`t seen the post, link of what you gave. What should I do if my post is a duplicate ?

Comment: take a look to the linked OP

Comment: I had already, thanks for the link.

Comment: @gimusi Problem is I don't know how to delete the post

Comment: Take a look here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24941/how-to-delete-posts-on-the-site